# How can I get browser authentication popup?

Tags: http, authentication, browser, http-headers, basic-authentication

Can anyone tell me, how can I get this browser authentication window ?

[image]

Answer (score 20):

This popup is part of the [HTTP-Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). In order to get it, you need to enable it in your web server. As Wikipedia puts it:

> When the server wants the user agent to authenticate itself towards
>   the server, it can send a request for authentication.
>
> This request should be sent using the **HTTP 401 Not Authorized** response
>   code containing a WWW-Authenticate HTTP header.
>
> The WWW-Authenticate header for basic authentication (used most often)
>   is constructed as following: `WWW-Authenticate: Basicrealm="insert realm"`

Comment: after enabling it, what code will i have to write ?

Comment: I think `WWW-Authenticate: Basicrealm="insert realm"` shoule be `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="insert realm"`

Answer (score 1):

That type of window pops up when a web server responds to a request by returning an "Unauthorized" (401) status code.  You'd have to tell the server to send that type of response in order to trigger the popup.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication you are talking is called Basic Authentication in web based application where browser popup will be used to get user credentials.

Which Java Application Server you are using ?

To know more about Basic Authentication look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security5.html) page

Comment: I am using Apache Tomcat