# Form handling through watir-webdriver or ruby or rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, watir-webdriver

How I can handle the sign-up form. It appears every time when I hit the url. I want dismiss it globally and also I want to access elements of it. How can I do that? using ruby, watir-webdriver, rspec or cucumber.

Comment: If it is a normal web form, then you interact with it just like you do everything else. Do you mean a basic authentication popup? (like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004942/how-can-i-get-browser-authentication-popup)

Comment: Yes, it's a modal- sign up form and I want to access or move focus on to it through a command for automating the application.

Comment: If it isn't basic authentication, then it sounds like you just want to learn how to use watir in general. https://watirwebdriver.com/

Comment: Please post the minimal amount of HTML and watir-webdriver code to reproduce the issue.  Otherwise, it's guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out (that is a line from watir-webdriver code):

```
browser.goto 'http://login:password@www.yoursite.com/index.html'
```

In other words you can send keys for basic HTTP authorisation right in the url like http://login:password@www.yoursite.com/index.html

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This is the right answer for basic authentication, but he said his issue is a modal sign up form and not basic authentication.

Comment: yes @titusfortner, so is there any way I can handle it?

Comment: I still have no idea what specifically you want to do. Please update your question with more specific information. Are you testing a page, scraping a page, or just looking to skip a page when you go to visit it? Have you used Watir for anything before? Are you asking for how to use Watir in general, or are you having a specific problem with it?